# Hash parameters access

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have loop and each iteration of Hash looks like this:

```
[1, {:clid=>1, :nvz=>4, :tip=>"IP", :name=>"Mark", :record=>"some text"}]
```

How I can access to this parameters in each iteration?
My first symbol "1" is manually set, would like to have it auto enumerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array and on array's second index you have a hash so first access your 2nd index of array and then you can access your hash values.

```
puts "ssssss", obj[1].clid.inspect
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Muhammad, you've pushed me in right way for solution!
 iteration[1][:clid]   - worked!